Cant resize windows
After upgrading to 24.04 yesterday and rebooting this morning, I am unable to resize some apps like Slack and VS Code.  When hovering the mouse over the edge of the app, I dont see the double arrow icon.
Chrome and Firefox are unexpected.  So might be electron apps?
Any ideas?  Its making the desktop unusable.

Although not a solution to the root cause, alt+F8 resizes the window in focus. Link to documentation here.

There is solution for VSCode.
Go to: File -> Preferences -> Settings
"window.titleBarStyle": "native"
solves the problem

This did nothing for me (that was already the setting): but there was help in the bug report on Github, and making those tweaks to the codium.desktop (in my case) file did the trick nicely.

I worked it out.  I had auto login onto the desktop.  Dunno how it impacted it but it did.

Changing from the "Ubuntu" desktop choice to the "Ubuntu Xorg" desktop choice allowed window sizing for me.  Not thrilled with that "solution" but it's a choice.
Log out.  Select user name, click the gear at the bottom right of the gdm screen and choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" and then supply password and log in.
